# relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.data'

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, ld, mingw-w64

I am running Windows 11 on an x64 machine and trying to run this x64 assembly program I wrote:

```
section .data
    var db 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    inc BYTE [var]   ; Increment the variable var by 1
    
    ; Exit the program
    mov eax, 60       ; System call number for "exit"
    xor edi, edi      ; Exit status code (0 for success)
    syscall
```

I expected it to increment `var` by 1, but I get this error:

```
main.o: in function `_start':
main.asm:(.text+0x3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.data'
```

I tried to change `db` to `dw`, I tried changing `BYTE` to `WORD`, and I tried to move `var` into `eax` and then use the `add` instruction, but none of that worked. I am using `NASM` and `ld`. Here is how I assembled and attempted to run my program:

```
nasm -f elf64 main.asm
ld main.o
```

If I run `ld --verbose`:

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.37
  Supported emulations:
   i386pep
   i386pe
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-x86-64)
SEARCH_DIR("=/c/temp/gcc/dest/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/c/temp/gcc/dest/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Make the virtual address and file offset synced if the alignment is
     lower than the target page size. */
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  . = ALIGN(__section_alignment__);
  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
    *(.text)
    *(SORT(.text$*))
     *(.text.*)
     *(.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    *(.glue_7t)
    *(.glue_7)
    . = ALIGN(8);
       /* Note: we always define __CTOR_LIST__ and ___CTOR_LIST__ here,
          we do not PROVIDE them.  This is because the ctors.o startup
          code in libgcc defines them as common symbols, with the
          expectation that they will be overridden by the definitions
          here.  If we PROVIDE the symbols then they will not be
          overridden and global constructors will not be run.
          See PR 22762 for more details.

          This does mean that it is not possible for a user to define
          their own __CTOR_LIST__ and __DTOR_LIST__ symbols; if they do,
          the content from those variables are included but the symbols
          defined here silently take precedence.  If they truly need to
          be redefined, a custom linker script will have to be used.
          (The custom script can just be a copy of this script with the
          PROVIDE() qualifiers added).
          In particular this means that ld -Ur does not work, because
          the proper __CTOR_LIST__ set by ld -Ur is overridden by a
          bogus __CTOR_LIST__ set by the final link.  See PR 46.  */
       ___CTOR_LIST__ = .;
       __CTOR_LIST__ = .;
       LONG (-1); LONG (-1);
       KEEP (*(.ctors));
       KEEP (*(.ctor));
       KEEP (*(SORT_BY_NAME(.ctors.*)));
       LONG (0); LONG (0);
       /* See comment about __CTOR_LIST__ above.  The same reasoning
          applies here too.  */
       ___DTOR_LIST__ = .;
       __DTOR_LIST__ = .;
       LONG (-1); LONG (-1);
       KEEP (*(.dtors));
       KEEP (*(.dtor));
       KEEP (*(SORT_BY_NAME(.dtors.*)));
       LONG (0); LONG (0);
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
    /* ??? Why is .gcc_exc here?  */
     *(.gcc_exc)
    PROVIDE (etext = .);
     KEEP (*(.gcc_except_table))
  }
  /* The Cygwin32 library uses a section to avoid copying certain data
     on fork.  This used to be named ".data".  The linker used
     to include this between __data_start__ and __data_end__, but that
     breaks building the cygwin32 dll.  Instead, we name the section
     ".data_cygwin_nocopy" and explicitly include it after __data_end__. */
  .data BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __data_start__ = . ;
    *(.data)
    *(.data2)
    *(SORT(.data$*))
    KEEP(*(.jcr))
    __data_end__ = . ;
    *(.data_cygwin_nocopy)
  }
  .rdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.rdata)
             *(SORT(.rdata$*))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __rt_psrelocs_start = .;
    KEEP(*(.rdata_runtime_pseudo_reloc))
    __rt_psrelocs_end = .;
  }
  __rt_psrelocs_size = __rt_psrelocs_end - __rt_psrelocs_start;
  ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
  __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
  ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = . - __rt_psrelocs_size;
  __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = . - __rt_psrelocs_size;
  .eh_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    KEEP (*(.eh_frame*))
  }
  .pdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    KEEP(*(.pdata*))
  }
  .xdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    KEEP(*(.xdata*))
  }
  .bss BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __bss_start__ = . ;
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
    __bss_end__ = . ;
  }
  .edata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.edata)
  }
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    *(.debug$S)
    *(.debug$T)
    *(.debug$F)
    *(.drectve)
     *(.note.GNU-stack)
     *(.gnu.lto_*)
  }
  .idata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* This cannot currently be handled with grouped sections.
        See pep.em:sort_sections.  */
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$2))
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$3))
    /* These zeroes mark the end of the import list.  */
    LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0);
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$4))
    __IAT_start__ = .;
    SORT(*)(.idata$5)
    __IAT_end__ = .;
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$6))
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$7))
  }
  .CRT BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    ___crt_xc_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XC*)))  /* C initialization */
    ___crt_xc_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xi_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XI*)))  /* C++ initialization */
    ___crt_xi_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xl_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XL*)))  /* TLS callbacks */
    /* ___crt_xl_end__ is defined in the TLS Directory support code */
    ___crt_xp_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XP*)))  /* Pre-termination */
    ___crt_xp_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xt_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.CRT$XT*)))  /* Termination */
    ___crt_xt_end__ = . ;
  }
  /* Windows TLS expects .tls$AAA to be at the start and .tls$ZZZ to be
     at the end of the .tls section.  This is important because _tls_start MUST
     be at the beginning of the section to enable SECREL32 relocations with TLS
     data.  */
  .tls BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    ___tls_start__ = . ;
    KEEP (*(.tls$AAA))
    KEEP (*(.tls))
    KEEP (*(.tls$))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.tls$*)))
    KEEP (*(.tls$ZZZ))
    ___tls_end__ = . ;
  }
  .endjunk BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* end is deprecated, don't use it */
    PROVIDE (end = .);
    PROVIDE ( _end = .);
     __end__ = .;
  }
  .rsrc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) : SUBALIGN(4)
  {
    KEEP (*(.rsrc))
    KEEP (*(.rsrc$*))
  }
  .reloc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.reloc)
  }
  .stab BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.stab)
  }
  .stabstr BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.stabstr)
  }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section.  Unlike other targets that fake this by putting the
     section VMA at 0, the PE format will not allow it.  */
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_aranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_aranges)
  }
  .zdebug_aranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_aranges)
  }
  .debug_pubnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_pubnames)
  }
  .zdebug_pubnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_pubnames)
  }
  /* DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_info BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*)
  }
  .zdebug_info BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_info .zdebug.gnu.linkonce.wi.*)
  }
  .debug_abbrev BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_abbrev)
  }
  .zdebug_abbrev BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_abbrev)
  }
  .debug_line BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_line)
  }
  .zdebug_line BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_line)
  }
  .debug_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_frame*)
  }
  .zdebug_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_frame*)
  }
  .debug_str BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_str)
  }
  .zdebug_str BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_str)
  }
  .debug_loc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_loc)
  }
  .zdebug_loc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_loc)
  }
  .debug_macinfo BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_macinfo)
  }
  .zdebug_macinfo BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_macinfo)
  }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions.  */
  .debug_weaknames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_weaknames)
  }
  .zdebug_weaknames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_weaknames)
  }
  .debug_funcnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_funcnames)
  }
  .zdebug_funcnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_funcnames)
  }
  .debug_typenames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_typenames)
  }
  .zdebug_typenames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_typenames)
  }
  .debug_varnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_varnames)
  }
  .zdebug_varnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_varnames)
  }
  /* DWARF 3.  */
  .debug_pubtypes BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_pubtypes)
  }
  .zdebug_pubtypes BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_pubtypes)
  }
  .debug_ranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_ranges)
  }
  .zdebug_ranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_ranges)
  }
  /* DWARF 4.  */
  .debug_types BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_types .gnu.linkonce.wt.*)
  }
  .zdebug_types BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_types .gnu.linkonce.wt.*)
  }
  /* DWARF 5.  */
  .debug_addr BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_addr)
  }
  .zdebug_addr BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_addr)
  }
  .debug_line_str BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_line_str)
  }
  .zdebug_line_str BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_line_str)
  }
  .debug_loclists BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_loclists)
  }
  .zdebug_loclists BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_loclists)
  }
  .debug_macro BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_macro)
  }
  .zdebug_macro BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_macro)
  }
  .debug_names BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_names)
  }
  .zdebug_names BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_names)
  }
  .debug_rnglists BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_rnglists)
  }
  .zdebug_rnglists BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_rnglists)
  }
  .debug_str_offsets BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_str_offsets)
  }
  .zdebug_str_offsets BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_str_offsets)
  }
  .debug_sup BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_sup)
  }
  /* For Go and Rust.  */
  .debug_gdb_scripts BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_gdb_scripts)
  }
  .zdebug_gdb_scripts BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_gdb_scripts)
  }
}


==================================================
```

When I did `ld main.o`, I got that error above. Any help would be appreciated, thanks! P.S I already looked at similar problems on this site, and tried the solutions, but they didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Are you running this in WSL/WSL2 on Windows? Although you say you are on 64-bit Windows, it seems you are trying to create and run a 64-bit Linux program.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am not totally sure. I do have Windows Subsystem for Linux enabled, but I am writing in Visual Studio Code, how can I check?

Comment: At the command prompt where you are executing commands like NASM and LD, what is returned by the command `uname -a` . If you get an error what is the error message you get? The fact you are using `elf64` and `ld` doesn't complain about the file format suggests your running commands in some kind of Linux. The assembly code you are using is using Linux syscalls (not Windows)

Comment: Does anything change if you use `inc BYTE [rel var]` instead?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes! rel var works! Could you make an asnwer explaining it? I would love to learn why that works!

Comment: I'm still real curious what the command `uname -a` shows and if it is an error message what the error message is.

Comment: It is an error message saying that the term 'uname' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Comment: OKay so that is in powershell (Windows). At the command prompt where you are using `nasm` and `ld` what is the output of the command ` ld --verbose`. It will be long. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Putting `rel` on memory references uses RIP (instruction pointer) relative addressing. If that worked you can make `rel` the default so you don't need `rel` on each memory reference by adding `default rel` at the top of your assembly file.

Comment: I'm really surprised using `nasm -f elf64` worked at all because you are clearly using a Native Windows LD from MinGW64. `-f win64` would be what I'd expect to be used. I would expect your code to crash when run given you can't use Linux system calls in a native windows application as they are not compatible.

Comment: Is there an alternative that would work? @MichaelPetch

Comment: If you are making Windows programs in assembler then you will need to link to things like the Win API and call Windows library functions that do what you need. To exit a program you'd have to use `ExitProcess` as an example.

Comment: You really need a tutorial on making Windows programs in assembly, you can't use Linux or MacOS example/tutorials. I don't know of any good ones myself. You'd have to Google around.

Comment: I really just went to chatGPT and asked it how to assemble and run an assembly program on x64 windows lmao.

Comment: This error message is identical to what you get for the same bug on Linux, if linking a PIE executable (like `ld -pie foo.o` or `gcc -nostdlib foo.o`).  [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) explains why RIP-relative addressing is necessary if 32-bit absolute won't work, and the NASM / machine-code details.  The only difference is you're linking into a Windows PE32+ executable, not a Linux ELF. Like Michael Petch, I'm a bit surprised GNU `ld` will accept ELF object files when linking a PE executable, but that is plausible.